# passing a file input from a form to another form in another page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to let the user to locate a file then I want to pass this file location input to another page where this file will be uploaded. I'm using java-script, php, html of course

Comment: How far have you got , have you read up on php file uploading ?

Comment: I know how to upload files but here I don't want to upload. I only want to pass a file location from a form in a page to another form in another page when redirecting from the first page. is it possible with cookie. how to store the file location in a cookie and let the other form obtains it.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this at all.  Most browsers will only set the value of a file input as a result of the user pressing the "Browse" button, to prevent unscrupulous servers from putting in a hidden file input that downloads a file the user may not want the server to have.

Comment: @Dave u r right. this cant be done in some browsers <http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/145162-setting-file-input-element>

Answer (score 1):

You can URL encode the file-path and pass it along as a get parameter. Then read it back in from $_GET[], urldecode it and put it in the form as its value="".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question really but take the GET or POST input from the form, process it and store the value in a SESSION variable. You can also run checks to make sure the file path follows a desired format prior to storing in SESSION as well.